# Looping and XLSXwriter formatting of a row

Tags: python, loops, xlsxwriter

I have a workbook with a number of sheets that I want to format after it's created, and I want to alter the colors of the header row based on column.  For example, I want the first 9 columns to be one color, then column 10 should be another, then all the rest should be a third color.

This is what I am looping through...it sort of works, but all the cells in row 0 end up the same color; the last color assigned always overwrites the previous columns.

```
visitFormat = mtbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#e9ccfc'})
cognotesFormat = mtbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#d2eff2'})
filedateFormat = mtbook.add_format({'bg_color':'#8cbcff'})

for worksheet in mtbook.worksheets():
    print(worksheet)
    # for every column
    for i in range(len(subreportCols)):
        # set header bgcolor based on current column (i)
        if [i] in range(0,11):
            useheader = visitFormat
        elif [i] == 10:
            useheader = cognotesFormat
        else:
            useheader = filedateFormat
        # Write the value from cell (first row, column=1) back into that cell with formatting applied
        worksheet.write(0, i, subreportCols[i], useheader)
```

I'm confused by this, since I thought it was writing each column separately.  Do I need to do this cell by cell somehow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it through troubleshooting, leaving up in case it helps someone else (*there is an "Answer Your Question" button, after all*).

In this line:

```
if [i] in range(0,11):
```

...what I thought I was doing was using [i] as a reference to the i'th value in my list, but I was actually referencing the WHOLE list.  I swapped out [i] for just i, and that worked fine.